# Sharepoint REST API GetFolderByServerRelativePath returns error when percent sign (%) is used in a folder name

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint

I use HTTP post method to upload files, as shown below:

```
POST https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/subsitename/pagename/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativepath(decodedurl=@t)/files/addusingpath(overwrite=true,decodedurl=@f)?@t='docs/%24%26%2B%2C%3B%3D%40%23%25%7B++++%7D%5E%7E%5B%5D%60'&@f='new.docx' HTTP/1.1

    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

It works well with any files and folders except folders with the percent sign ("%") in a folder name.
If destination folder name consists a percent sign ("%") it returns the error with message:

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147024893, System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"File Not Found."}}}
```

I've found the related article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/supporting-and-in-file-and-folder-with-the-resourcepath-api

Therefore, I tried to use another post method:

```
POST https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/subsitename/pagename/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativepath(decodedurl=@t)/files/addstubusingpath(decodedurl=@f)?@t='docs/%24%26%2B%2C%3B%3D%40%23%25%7B++++%7D%5E%7E%5B%5D%60'&@f='new.docx' HTTP/1.1

    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

But I got a response like below:

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Not well formatted JSON stream."}}}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing was in encoding space sign as "%20" instead of "+" and using query below to create a folder:

```
/_api/web/folders/AddUsingPath(decodedurl="folder%20name")
```

And then add a file to the folder by query:

```
_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativepath(decodedurl='docs/%24%26%2B%2C%3B%3D%40%23%25%7B%20%20%20%20%7D%5E%7E%5B%5D%60')/files/AddUsingPath(overwrite=true,decodedurl='new.docx')
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: Microsoft's documentation doesn't mention AddUsingPath. They suggest AddStubUsingPath. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, do you have a link to the documentation for AddStubUsingPath?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test result with Fiddler, You may check it.

```
/sites/Developer/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativepath(decodedurl='/sites/Developer/MyDoc3/Fo%25lder')/Files/add(url='test.txt',overwrite=true)
```

[image]